# Condition for matrix being Hermitian

Tags: linear-algebra

In a book that I'm reading the following property is stated:
If for a matrix $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ it holds that $(Ax,x) \in \mathbb{R}, \forall x \in \mathbb{C}^n$ then the matrix is Hermitian.

You can use the fact that every matrix can be decomposed in an Hermitian matrix and a skew-Hermitian matrix (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew-Hermitian_matrix). I was struggling with it a few hours but I don't manage to prove it. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\varepsilon_1,\dots,\varepsilon_n$ be the orthonormal basis.
$$
(A\varepsilon_i,\varepsilon_i)=a_{ii}\Rightarrow a_{ii}\in \mathbb{R}.
$$
$$
(A(\varepsilon_i+\varepsilon_j),\varepsilon_i+\varepsilon_j)=a_{ii}+a_{jj}+a_{ij}+a_{ji}\Rightarrow a_{ij}+a_{ji}=2x\in\mathbb{R}.
$$
$$
(A(i\varepsilon_i+i\varepsilon_j),\varepsilon_i+\varepsilon_j)=a_{ii}-a_{jj}-i(a_{ij}-a_{ji})\Rightarrow a_{ij}-a_{ji}=2iy,\quad y\in\mathbb{R}.
$$
Then we have
$$
a_{ij}=x+iy{}\\
a_{ji}=x-iy.
$$